# I want to search a position in google maps with the searchbox in a prompt

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I make a prompt in HTML that searches a google maps position? i already have the google maps. And a button that gives me a prompt (with textbox). But how can i search from that textbox my given position?? help me plz

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLZ9u.png)
Like this but now i want a result in google maps.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the location to variables so for example that you get from

```
var x = prompt("What is the longitude?");
var y = prompt("What is the latitude?");
```

that way you'll set the location based on the prompts

Comment: what do you mean? how are you using google maps? If you're using an API there should be somewhere where you put in the location. Just replace that with x and y

Comment: see the picture

Comment: the image isn't showing anything useful. It's much better if you show us the code. It's impossible to know how the code looks based on an image.